# How to make a WPF Checkbox control's IsChecked property truly OneWay?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a Grid that handles Tap events via a trigger behavior. Inside this Grid are a Checkbox and a TextBlock, and I put multiple of these Grids is in a Listview as ListViewItems.

The Checkbox's IsChecked Binds to a boolean property. What I want to achieve is that the checkbox UI itself represents the current state of this property, but if I tap on the checkmark only the grid (the parent container) handles it.

To summarize, IsChecked should follow the property I specified in the ViewModel, but the checkbox should not react to any tap events in itself and leave that to its parent. (Since I use a command as a receiver I did not find a way to access the Tap Events arguments.)

I tried IsHitTestVisible, and it messes with the visual template, same as setting Disabled (since the checkbox should behave just as it would if it were enabled).

The control itself is a TreeView, basically making indents with margins in a Listview.

Comment: Do you have a code example? This works fine for me with a checkbox inside another button. The button is handling the interaction, and the checkbox is `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

Comment: I could not come up with a realistically short snippet that demonstrates it, but if I set IsHitTestVisible to false then the checkbox binding does not work for me. Seems like the property gets set correctly (since it is on VM side), but the control does not enter its 'Selected' state

Comment: I suspect the issue is actually in your ViewModel or Binding, and then when IsHitTestVisible isn't set (or is true) the checkbox is just being updated in the view. Are you raising PropertyChanged events from your ViewModel?